Load more items using React
I need to load more items in a table using React. When I click on the Load More button, the application should keep the previous items and load more items. I tried to perform this action in the handleClick function, however, the code did nothing. My current code is:

export function TableClients({ result, title }: ITableComponent) {
  const [clients, setClients] = useState([]);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const clientsPerPage = 10;
  const [displayedClientsCount, setDisplayedClientsCount] = useState(clientsPerPage);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchClients = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/clients', {
        params: {
          page: currentPage - 1,
          size: clientsPerPage,
        },
      });

      setClients(response.data.content);
    };
    fetchClients();
  }, [currentPage, searchTerm, sortOrder]);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setDisplayedClientsCount(prevCount => prevCount + clientsPerPage);
  };
  return (
    <Box>
      <TableHeader
        title={title}
        result={result}
      />
      <Table>
        <Table.Thead>
          <Table.Tr>
            <Table.Th>Cliente</Table.Th>
          </Table.Tr>
        </Table.Thead>
        <Table.Tbody>
        {clients.slice(0, displayedClientsCount).map((client: IClient, index) => (
            <Table.Tr>
              <Client
              name={(client as IClient).name}
              />
            </Table.Tr>
        ))}
        </Table.Tbody>
      </Table>
      <Flex>
      <Button       
        variant="filled"
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        Load more
      </Button>
    </Flex>
    </Box>
  );
}```


The problem you're seeing is because you're not fetching more values when you update your displayedClientsCount variable.
You're fetching clientsPerPage (in your case 10) clients on initial page load, so all you can display is 10 total until you fetch more.
To solve this, I would take the fetchClients code out of your useEffect, and call it again when you click the "Load more" button. I recommend updating the currentPage variable and calling the fetchClients in an Effect after the state updates. Then, append the results of that fetch to your clients state. You can also get rid of your displayedClientsCount, since your component will only render what is in the clients state.
Here's an example:
export function TableClients({ result, title }: ITableComponent) {
  const [clients, setClients] = useState([]);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const clientsPerPage = 10;

  const fetchClients = async (page: number, size: number) => {
    const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/clients', {
      params: {
        page,
        size,
      },
  });

  useEffect(() => {
      const newClients = fetchClients(currentPage - 1, clientsPerPage);
      setClients([...clients, ...newClients.data.content]);
  }, [setClients, currentPage]);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setCurrentPage(prevCount => prevCount + clientsPerPage);
  };
  return (
    <Box>
      <TableHeader
        title={title}
        result={result}
      />
      <Table>
        <Table.Thead>
          <Table.Tr>
            <Table.Th>Cliente</Table.Th>
          </Table.Tr>
        </Table.Thead>
        <Table.Tbody>
        {clients.map((client: IClient, index) => (
            <Table.Tr>
              <Client
              name={(client as IClient).name}
              />
            </Table.Tr>
        ))}
        </Table.Tbody>
      </Table>
      <Flex>
      <Button       
        variant="filled"
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        Load more
      </Button>
    </Flex>
    </Box>
  );
}

